# Why am I getting an error when using the array I generated from an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I am trying to manipulate an array the was created from an observable but the only way i could access that array or to the only thing it exist is `console.log`.

This is the ts

```
constructor(public serVice: SerService) {
  this.serVice.lineupp$.subscribe({ 
    next: (value: any) => this.serVice.racers.push(value[0]);
                        
    for (i = 0; i <= this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position.length -1; i++) {
      this.serVice.sections.push(this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position[i]);
      this.serVice.sections.push(this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[1].position[i]);
    }
  })
}
```

I figured that TS won't allow more than

```
this.serVice.lineupp$.subscribe({
  next: (value: any) => this.serVice.racers.push(value[0]);
```

When i place the code outside

```
constructor(public serVice: SerService) {
  this.serVice.lineupp$.subscribe({
    next: (value: any) => this.serVice.racers.push(value[0]);
  })

  for (i = 0; i <= this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position.length -1; i++) {
    this.serVice.sections.push(this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position[i]);
    this.serVice.sections.push(this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[1].position[i]);
  }
}
```

Same issue this break the code.

What I was trying to do is perform certain operation on the array that way created from push the contents of the Observable using subscribe.

This is error

[image: Console Error]

Comment: can you describe more about the question also about the service lineupp$

Comment: serVice.lineupp$ is an Observable of

`      this.a_s.lineupp$ = this.serVice.x$.pipe(switchMap((x) => {
        return this.db.list('lineups/'+x).valueChanges();
    }))`

I am then trying to create a regular array from that. It works just fine, till I start trying to access values from inside the array. Then console throws an error of Undefined. But when I console log the array at the top level everything is fine. Like `console.log(this.serVice.racers)` works fine if i go deeper into the array like `console.log(this.serVice.racers[0].lineups)` the code breaks the app.

Comment: Ok, can I get the value of console.log(this.serVice.racers) ? or a stackblitz

Comment: This is from console `Array []
​
0: Object { lineups: (2) […], sport_event: {…} }
​​​​
lineups: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
event: Object { id: "race_name" }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []`

Comment: code looks ok, but looks like some typo error need to have more context about this to solve the issue

Comment: another issue if I `console.log(this.serVice.racers)` works fine .  But, if I `console.log(this.serVice.racers[0])` comes back as undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256849/discussion-between-almostasnecessary-and-aniket-gawas).

Comment: Please come on chat

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stack snippet with comments to help you better understand the problem

```js
// below is an arrow function, notice that it does not have brackets
const test = () => 'hello';
// the below line will output 'hello' since there is no brackets, the first line will always be returned by the function
console.log(test());

// below is an arrow function, notice that it has brackets
const testy = () => {
    console.log('notice how I can do extra work, before the value gets returned!');
    return 'hello2';
};
// the below line will output 'hello2' but we can also do extra work because when we define brackets, we control which line returns the value!
console.log(testy());
```

I hope the above snippets helps you understand the difference between an arrow function with and without brackets, so lets look at your angular code!

code main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';
import { SerService } from './ser.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(public serVice: SerService) {
    this.serVice.lineupp$.subscribe({
      next: (value: any) => {
        this.serVice.racers.push(value[0]);
        for (
          let i = 0; // <- changed here, we need to add let to defined the variable (!Important)
          i <= this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position.length - 1;
          i++
        ) {
          this.serVice.sections.push(
            this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[0].position[i]
          );
          this.serVice.sections.push(
            this.serVice.racers[0].lineups[1].position[i]
          );
        }

        console.log('this.serVice.sections', this.serVice.sections);
        console.log('this.serVice.racers', this.serVice.racers);
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SerService {
  racers: any[] = [];
  sections: any[] = [];

  lineupp$ = of([
    {
      lineups: [{ position: [1, 2] }, { position: [3, 4] }],
    },
  ]);

  constructor() {}
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pjbgpa?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fser.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)